# WP 8.1 add cards to wallet without 3rd party app?

Tags: 8.1, wallet

Is there any way to add cards to my wallet WITHOUT a 3rd party app like it tries to give me when I tap the + button? With WP 8 you could select the kind of card (visa, other...). Is this possible with 8.1?

Comment: I think you have to add the credit card to your MS account directly, rather than in the Wallet. You can do so at https://commerce.microsoft.com

Comment: That's almost what I want. That allows adding credit cards, but what about things like library cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add additional cards by downloading the .mswallet file from the provider's website. There is a [quickstart guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631256) that you could point your local, friendly, library at, if they don't do this already (or you *could* roll your own, based on that documentation)